# Pattern search the user input in a file in Unix using awk

Tags: bash, unix, awk

I am trying to write awk script to search for a pattern that is given input by user, in a file.
My code look like this:
`awk 'BEGIN{printf "Enter : ";getline input<"/dev/tty"} /'"$input"'/ {print}' <abc.txt`
What I get as an output is the whole file. Can someone help me to find where I'm going wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you do is:
you read the pattern from tty,
you place it into a variable of awk (not of the shell) called input,
then you match the line of the content of a **shell** variable called input. (Just look at the quotes and try to interpret the code yourself.) That variable is empty so awk matches the line against //, an empty regexp that always matches.

All you need to do is

```
$0 ~ input { print }
```

or

```
match( $0, input) { print }
```

Actually "{ print }" can be omitted becaus the default action for any matching matter is to print the record.

Comment: Thanks @Sándor for sorting out the error. I was pulling my hair out for this. :)

Comment: Very welcome. I can imagine. Sometimes it quoting makes even simple cases look harder, other times it really _makes_ them harder.